# jQuery AJAX with IE8

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer-8

I am attempting to implement a get request via `$.ajax` upon the user submitting a form.

I am not sure if what I am doing is the most efficient method (binding a click to the form button) so if there is a more efficient way (or standard way), please suggest it!

My result is that the content div is filled properly in FF/Chrome, but IE it is not. IE seems to be submitting the form and reloading the page entirely.

In addition, I really do think I need to "submit" the form, because I want to take advantage of jQuery `validate();` which does not work with the below implementation (even in FF/Chrome).

**Javascript**:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $("#theForm").submit(function(){
       // build our data to send in our request
       var mydata = {method: "search", color: $('#color').val()};

       $.ajax({
           url: 'foo.php',
           data: mydata,
           type: 'get',
           dataType: 'json',
           success: function(data){
              $("#content").html(data);
           }
           error: function(e){
             console.log(e.message);
           }
       });
    return false;
   });
});
```

**HTML** :

```
<form id="search">
       <input type="submit" />
</form>

<div id="content"></div>
```

Comment: change your `dataType : json` to `dataType: 'json'` (with the quotes around json)

Comment: also, you have a `,` missed after `type: 'get'`,not sure if that is a typo when  you pasted the code here

Comment: You should also handle the case of submitting the form by hitting Enter!!

Comment: Those were just typo's Claudio, thanks though!

Comment: typo or no typo, dataType is wrong for returning html.

Comment: I'm returning JSON, myData is a structure of params I am sending, I didn't include it as it wasn't relevant.

Answer (score 3):

You should change your submit button to be of type button. Inputs of type submit automatically post the page and in your case this is not necessary.

```
<input type="button" id="search-button">
```

Otherwise you can prevent the default action of the button using [event.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/).

```
$("#search-button").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        url: 'foo.php',
        data: mydata,
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success: function(data){
            $("#content").html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Since you are expecting html back from the server, it is best to specify the `dataType` that you are expecting is actually html. Note, you previously had json to be the `dataType`. You can also specify the type of data you are passing to the server using `contentType` which in your case is json so you should use `application/json`.

Per your comments, your dataType should be json.

I just noticed that it seems your `$(document).ready(function() {});` does not seem to be closed. You seemed to have forgot the `);`. Is this a copy paste issue?

After your most recent code edit, you seem to be missing a comma between your success and error.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'foo.php',
    data: mydata,
    type: 'get',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){
        $("#content").html(data);
    }, // <---
    error: function(e){
         console.log(e.message);
    }
});
```

Comment: I am getting JSON back from the server

Comment: Why are you putting straight json into a div? Are you just getting back a string?

Comment: Josh, I'm just putting it there for testing. Going to format it later. Point is, IE is submitting the form (page is refreshing) where as FF and Chrome are behaving as expected.

Comment: Your $(document).ready(function() {}); does not seem to be closed.

Comment: It seems closed on my end, I'd think FF or Chrome would complain / not work if that were the case. Sublime text also is aligning my brackets properly, so I can confirm the syntax is ok.

Comment: @Jason Wells Must have been a copy paste issue. Did you try using event.preventDefault()?

Comment: I did, no dice :( Is there additional debugging tools for IE that might help me? I am able to alert the "myData" variable in IE right before the start of the ajax call, so it definitely is getting to that point.

Comment: @Jason Wells You are missing a comma after your success and before your error.

Comment: Sorry,  it's there on my page - I didn't copy and paste the exact code for privacy purposes.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12617/discussion-between-josh-mein-and-jason-wells)

Answer (score 0):

You should bind on the submit event of the form, and cancel the default event - which is submitting the form (either by [`event.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) or simply `return false;`, which [will also stop propagation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/event-preventdefault-vs-return-false)).

```
<form id="theForm">
<input type="submit" id="search-button">
</form>


$("#theForm").submit(function(){

 $.ajax({
    url: 'foo.php',
    data: mydata,
    type: 'get',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){
          $("#content").html(data);
      }
  });

  return false;
});
```

Also notice that `json` should be the string `'json'` in `dataType`. You could also consider using [`getJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/). I also cleaned some unnecessary characters from the code.

Comment: Thanks, it still is working in FF, but IE is still reloading the page entirely, with no errors in the log.

Comment: FWIW, it's not getting to the success attribute of my ajax call.. if I throw an alert() within success it comes up in FF, but not IE

Comment: @JasonWells Could you set up some kind of demo or test case? This code should work.

Comment: Sure, let me see what I can do on jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

I finally tried calling a free-standing function:

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    ,success: function(data){
        updCont(data)
    }
...
});
function updCont(htm){
    $("#content").html(htm);
}
```

I lost a couple of **DAYS** on this problem! Nightmare over. Maybe IE8 doesn't trust foreign content so disallows inserting new content from AJAX, while an already existing function has more power and less browser security issues?

Oh, yeh, also check out `event.preventDefault()` to keep the `submit()` action from taking over